# Selenium Error: StaleElementReferenceException in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on an application that downloads images from the internet in Selenium. However, I get the same error in the code seen in the picture and I cannot continue the process. This code, you can see the error in the image below.

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        int PictureID = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ChromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeService);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://oblivious212.artstation.com/");
            var Projects = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("album-grid-item"));
            for(int i = 0; i < Projects.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (Projects.ElementAt(i) == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Projects[i].Click();
                var Images = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));
                for(int x = 0; x < Images.Count(); x++)
                {
                        PictureID++;
                        WebClient Downloader = new WebClient();
                        var ImageUrl = Images[x].GetAttribute("src");
                        var ImageName = Images[x].GetAttribute("alt");
                        Downloader.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, "C:\\Users\\DeLL\\Pictures\\Images\\" + ImageName + PictureID + ".jpg");
                }
            driver.Navigate().Back();
            }
```

Screenshot of exception when running in debug mode:

[image: Error is here.]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you navigate to a new page, which I guess is what your `Projects[i].Click();` call does, any `IWebElement` objects you saved from an earlier page (`oblivious212.artstation.com/`) become "stale" and you can no longer use them. You must design your code around this fact; there are several ways you might do this.

Basically, while you're still on page `oblivious212.artstation.com/`, you need to save off any data you need from the `IWebElement` objects returned by your `driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("album-grid-item"))` call, into a local object, rather than saving the `IWebElement` objects themselves. Then, replace your `Projects[i].Click();` call with code which uses your saved local data, rather than using the `IWebElement` objects themselves.